# Remove component from a DOM programmatically Vue 3

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, vue-component, vuejs3

I am making something similar to sheet with cells where using drag and drop i can move events, that are components, around.

Since it is possible to add component from any file like this

```
import event from "event.vue"

let el = document.getElementById("div")
        const newComponent = createApp(event)
        newComponent.mount(el)
```

Im trying to remove it somehow aswell, but i had no luck to find solution.
i have tried to this

```
let element = document.getElementById("newComponent")
element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
```

It's kind of working, but i can't add new component to same div because there is dataset remaining 'data-v-app' and i guess its because old component was not removed. Is there a way to do this or maybe vue isn't capable?

Comment: Why not use a `v-if`? https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if

Comment: @kissu I will probably do that if i my question will not be answered. I want to know all possibilities. I have planned out both scenarious and `v-if` is more complex so far.

Answer (score 1):

`v-if` is still the "official" way of doing things here because it uses Vue's reactivity.
Modifying the DOM is not recommended since it's imperative, like jQuery: you need to tell the language how to do things, so you need to take care of finding the selector, ask it to do things on it, and loop that process in case of an event listener or alike.

VueJS is declarative, so the API is far less complex. You tell what variable is bind to what and when the variable mutate, it will react accordingly to the changes without you needing to tell step by step what to do.

---

When you project grows, an imperative approach like jQuery or your vanilla JS (`document.getElementById`) will not be efficient because you will need to describe everything that happens once you mutate a variable. If 12 things depend on a thing, you will need pretty much the double of lines of code for each of them.

While in Vue, you will make some conditions thanks to the API and it will make those changes by itself. The complexity is then greatly reduced. On top of having powerful directives + Vue devtools to help you.

---

Add to that the fact that if you mix both some Vue state + imperative coding, you will have the worst of 2 worlds. You will need to do funky things to kinda keep the reactivity + will still need to write declarative code.

Hence why, people are using Vue's API + [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) **only** when needed.
Stay away from imperative coding: jQuery, manually selecting DOM elements etc...you will have an easier time, less complexity and more performance by far.

---

Vue/React exist for a reason, mainly removing complexity. Use them to their full potential.